# Hook to call a function after menu rebuild?

Tags: 7, javascript, navigation

After a menu rebuild, such as one that occurs automatically when visiting the Modules admin page, some of my Drupal JS behaviors are not in the correct state. I need to re-initialize or attach them after a menu_rebuild() occurs.

Is there a hook I can use or a way I can know to call a JS function after a rebuild?

Comment: Are your JS behaviors running with a .once?  Can you provide a JS snippet on your block of code, starting with Drupal.behaviors.myBehaviorExample{} ?

Comment: Even if I put what I want to call outside of the once, just in `attach()`, it is not called. attachBehaviors is not called after a menu reload.